# cloudflare api srv add php

Tags: php, api, cloudflare, srv

Hi I am trying to make a script that adds a SRV records to cloudflare, but cant get it to work :(

```php
<?php
include_once("includes/class_cloudflare.php");

$domain = 'game-panel.dk';
$type = 'SRV';
$name = 'testing';
$content = 'myip';
$ttl = '1';
$mode = '0';
$prio = '5';


$service = '_ts3';
$srvname = 'testing';
$protocol = 'UDP';
$weight = '1';
$port = '10002';
$target = 'testing.game-panel.dk';

$cf = new cloudflare_api("my@email.dk", "mycloudflareapikey");
$response = $cf->rec_new($domain, $type, $name, $content, $ttl, $mode, $prio);

print_r($response);
?>
```

I get this response:

```
stdClass Object ( [request] => stdClass Object ( [act] => rec_new ) [result] => error [msg] => Invalid service value. [err_code] => service- )
```

I use this class:

https://github.com/vexxhost/CloudFlare-API/blob/master/class_cloudflare.php

Comment: Please explain how you have fixed it for the benefit of future users.

Answer (score 1):

Updated & Fully Functional code added below :D

```
    <?php
    require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/cloudflare/class_cloudflare.php");
    $cf = new cloudflare_api("E-Mail", "API Key");

    $domain = "domain.tld";
    $type = "SRV";
    $name = "ts3";
    $content = "1.1.1.1";
    $ttl = "1";
    $mode = "0";
    $prio = "5";


    $service = "_ts3";
    $srvname = "testing";
    $protocol = "_udp";
    $weight = "1";
    $port = "10002";
    $target = "test.domain.tld";

    // Add (SRV) AND (A) RECORD TO CLOUDFLARE.
    $response2 = $cf->rec_new($domain, $type, $name, $content, $ttl, $mode, $prio, $service, $srvname, $protocol, $weight, $port, $target);
    $response = $cf->rec_new($domain, 'A', $name, $content, $ttl, $mode, $service_mode = '1');  

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response2);
    echo "</pre>";  
?>
```

Comment: I just did this here hope you can use it, or I could paste my of my code: http://nopaste.php-quake.net/373522

Comment: Oops ignore that I didn't see your link

Comment: Just tried it with yours and it still does not work :(, I edited the code above to include your version.

Comment: I managed to do it :), I just edited the above code to show the full PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must create new zone and register domain name.
2. After step 1 you can create dns record... (Try this https://github.com/Silent-Force/CloudFlare-API)
3. You must specify the correct URL address for the request, and select the Request method. official documentation - https://api.cloudflare.com/